# Camel Bindy separator in extended ascii code

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, extended-ascii, bindy

I am using Camel Bindy to process csv files that I recieve from a third party company.

In their csv they are using a separator that is in the extended ascii table: "\u00a4" (code 164 in decimal).

I have tried to set bindy up like this:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\u00a4")
```

But it fails to separate the columns

When I change the csv separator by something more standard like ";" everything works fine. As this csv is sent from an external company I can't change it myself.

Is there a way I can setup Bindy to support this?

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "§")
public class Employee {

@DataField(pos = 1)
private String employeeId;
@DataField(pos = 2, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date startDate;
@DataField(pos = 3, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date endDate;
@DataField(pos = 4)
private Character code;

// Getters and Setters
```

}

CSV content:
    "aC1aoC3"§"12/04/2017"§"12/04/2017"§"A"
    "aC1aoC3"§"13/04/2017"§"13/04/2017"§"A"
    "aC1aoC3"§"14/04/2017"§"14/04/2017"§"A"
    "aC1aoC3"§"15/04/2017"§"15/04/2017"§"A"
    "aC1aoC3"§"16/04/2017"§"16/04/2017"§"U"
    "aC1aoC3"§"17/04/2017"§"17/04/2017"§"U"
    "aC1aoC3"§"18/04/2017"§"18/04/2017"§"U"

Many thanks for your help

Gilles

Comment: Could you please include a sample csv (which can't be parsed by bindy) in your question?

Comment: I have added it to the problem description. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

can you try case 3 and case 4 which are listed in Camel bindy

http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html

[different case's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WABQO.png)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this: @CsvRecord(separator = "\"¤\"") and this 
@CsvRecord(separator = "\"\u00a4\""). With no success. Bindy takes the whole line with the first field

Comment: can you post the actual record (from file ) and the POJO class ?

Comment: Added. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `section sign (§)` is 167 in decimal not 164.

Change the separator to `\u00A7` like this:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\u00A7")
public class Employee { ... }
```

Comment: I think I have an encoding issue because in the string received from Bindy I have the replacement sequence 65533 instead of the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
It was an encoding issue. The character could not be read and was replaced by the 65533 (unicode) replacement character.

I solved it by setting charset=ISO-8859-1 to the ftp connection reading the csv file.